# Asset Library not shown in preferences

Tags: customization, asset-browser, library

How can i activate the asset libraries in preferences if its not shown? [image]

Comment: Hello, what Blender version are you using?

Comment: Version 3.6.1..

Comment: Should be there by default. Is the Asset Browser workspace shown on the top bar and is it available in the top-left Areas dropdown? If not, there's something very wrong and I'd reinstall from a new download.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Preferences>File paths

Here screenshot in Blender 4.1

[image]